# pip not upgrading outdated package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install some outdated pip packages, one of which is `dbus-python`, but when trying to install I get the following error.
The `pip` version is 22.3.1.

```
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.3.2.tar.gz (605 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [121 lines of output]
      The Meson build system
      Version: 0.64.0
      Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f
      Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f/.mesonpy-8vj2xlef/build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: dbus-python
      Project version: 1.3.2
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-declaration-after-statement: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-inline: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-redundant-decls: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-switch-default: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-write-strings: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdouble-promotion: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-cond: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnull-dereference: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-enum: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wjump-misses-init: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-sign: YES
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES
      Configuring _dbus-python-config.h using configuration
      
      Executing subproject dbus-gmain
      
      dbus-gmain| Project name: dbus-gmain
      dbus-gmain| Project version: undefined
      dbus-gmain| C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.4.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0")
      dbus-gmain| C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdouble-promotion: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-branches: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-cond: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnull-dereference: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wredundant-decls: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-default: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-enum: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wwrite-strings: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdeclaration-after-statement: YES
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wjump-misses-init: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-sign: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES (cached)
      dbus-gmain| Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
      dbus-gmain| Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.24.1)
      dbus-gmain| Run-time dependency dbus-1 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
      
      ../../subprojects/dbus-gmain/meson.build:107:0: ERROR: Dependency "dbus-1" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
      
      A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f/.mesonpy-8vj2xlef/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
      + meson setup --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f/.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2 --prefix=/usr /tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f /tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f/.mesonpy-8vj2xlef/build
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/fra/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/fra/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/fra/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 969, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          with _project(config_settings) as project:
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 948, in _project
          with Project.with_temp_working_dir(
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
          return next(self.gen)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 777, in with_temp_working_dir
          yield cls(source_dir, tmpdir, build_dir)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 682, in __init__
          self._configure(reconfigure=bool(build_dir) and not native_file_mismatch)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 713, in _configure
          self._meson(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 696, in _meson
          return self._proc('meson', *args)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-6wo83trl/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mesonpy/__init__.py", line 691, in _proc
          subprocess.check_call(list(args))
        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['meson', 'setup', '--native-file=/tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f/.mesonpy-native-file.ini', '-Ddebug=false', '-Doptimization=2', '--prefix=/usr', '/tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f', '/tmp/pip-install-kmtrg17g/dbus-python_2d462e86e87e41aea13006f07b047f3f/.mesonpy-8vj2xlef/build']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No package 'dbus-1' found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285415/no-package-dbus-1-found)

Comment: A bit more in detail to @Michael Ruth's suggestion, you could give a try: `$ sudo apt install build-essential libpython3-dev libdbus-1-dev`

Comment: it seems it solved. I am not pretty sure it was the only thing I did but for now it's working.